# Randomly Blink LEDs

Tags: assembly, microcontroller

6 led are needed to be programmed in such a way that they blink randomly. There will be total of 3 blinks. Any of the 3 out of 6 leds should blink.

I am not getting an idea, how that should be done. Please guide about the algorithm or procedure which should be followed to achieve this.

The code should be for hc11 and is to be written in assembly.

Comment: There are 2^6 = 64 possible patterns.  Only a subset of them have exactly 3 bits set to 1.  Write down a list of them,  generate a random integer that indexes that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the exact specs for your device, but setting the LED's is usually just a matter of setting a bit. If you don't have access to a sudo-random number generator, you can make a cheap one by messing with multiplications and throwing sub-register values around. (Trial and error with that can take you far.) Any values you generate should keep static records to seed your next value. You can mod/shift/etc. any value you get down into a bit place for one of your LED's. Just Shift your 1 by the random offset to a resulting random position. If you need all three random positions to light up at once, just find random positions three times, retrying if you ever get a repeat, then OR the results together to get your LED driving value. (011010, 100011,...)

Hope this helps. It's a pretty basic exercise.